# Address out of range error for register a1

Tags: assembly, mips

I do not understand why i am getting this address out of range error. I am working on the sum2 function using indexing of the array. I am trying to load the values for B into the $a1 register

line 32: Runtime exception at 0x00400018: address out of range 0x20020018

```
    .data

A:  .word 0,0,0
B:  .word 0,0,0

    .text
main:   

    jal read_A


sum2:
    li  $t7, 0
    la  $t5, B

    lw  $a1, B($t5)
    add $t7,$t7,$a1

    addi    $t5, $t5, 4

    lw   $a1, B($t5)
    add $t7, $t7, $a1

    addi    $t5, $t5, 4

    lw  $a1, B($t5)
    add $t7, $t7, $a1

    jr  $ra

sum1:
    li  $t9, 0

    la  $t0, A
    lw  $a0, ($t0)
    add $t9,$t9,$a0

    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    lw   $a0, ($t0)
    add $t9, $t9, $a0

    la  $t0, A+8
    lw  $a0, ($t0)
    add $t9, $t9, $a0

    jr  $ra

    .data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter three integers:\n"

    .text
read_A:
    la  $a0, prompt
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall

    li      $v0, 5 #read first integer
    syscall

    sw  $v0, A  #Save first integer

    li  $v0, 5  #save second integer
    syscall

    sw  $v0, A+4 #Save second integer

    li  $v0, 5
    syscall

    sw  $v0, A+8 #save 3rd integer

    jr $ra
```

Comment: You perhaps were accidentally doubling a pointer.  Data normally starts at address 0x10010000, and your faulting access was trying to get address 0x20020018.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it had to do with the register i was putting in the array index bracket